# Calculate in Method of dimensional regularization with normalization on physical masses

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, dimensional-regularization

I have this question that says Calculate

[image]

in Method of dimensional regularization with normalization on physical masses. any idea how should I begin?

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment so I answer here.

I suppose that $\Pi^{(1)}_{\mu \nu}$ stands for the first order photon self-energy loop. You can have a look to that document at page 30 https://homepages.dias.ie/ydri/qft_chap_five.pdf
Or if you can have access to the book "Quantum Field Theory" from Mandl and Shaw section 10.4 you would get a similar derivation in a easily understandable way.

The steps are more or less the following:

1. You begin with the usual amplitude but you now integrate over $d^Dp$ so you also need to change the power of the factor $(2\pi)^{-4}$ into $(2\pi)^{-D}$.
2. You evaluate the trace.
3. You use a Feynman parametrization, so instead of having one integral of a product of 2 terms in the denominator you now get one more integral over an additional parameter of something squared in the denominator.
4. You evaluate the integral over $d^Dp$ using standard integrals.
5. You set $D=4-\eta$, take the limit $\eta \rightarrow 0$ and use $x^{-\eta /2} = 1 - \frac{\eta}{2}ln(x) + ...$ as well as $\Gamma(\eta /2) = \frac{\eta}{2} - \gamma + ...$ (where $\gamma$ is the Euler's constant) to simplify the expression.

I hope it helps you :)

Comment: thank you so much for taking the time and answering I very much appreciate it )